# Laravel POST Method returning Status: 405 Method Not Allowed on a POST method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, thunderclient

Please find the info below:

**NoteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\NoteRequest;
use App\Models\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class NoteController extends Controller
{
    public function index():JsonResponse
    {
        $notes = Note::all();
        return response()->json($notes, 200);
    }

    public function store(NoteRequest $request):JsonResponse
    {
        $note = Note::create( $request->all() );
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $note
        ], 201);
    }

    public function show($id):JsonResponse
    {
        $note = Note::find($id);
        return response()->json($note, 200);
    }

    public function update(NoteRequest $request, $id):JsonResponse
    {
        $note = Note::find($id);
        $note->update($request->all());
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $note,
        ], 200);
    }

    public function destroy($id):JsonResponse
    {
        Note::find($id)->delete();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

**NoteRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class NoteRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title', 'required|max:255|min:3',
            'content', 'nullable|max:255|min:10',
        ];
    }
}
```

**Note.php (model)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

**api.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\NoteController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/note', NoteController::class);
});
```

**php artisan route:list**

```
GET|HEAD        / ......................................................................................................................  
  POST            _ignition/execute-solution ............... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController  
  GET|HEAD        _ignition/health-check ........................... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController  
  POST            _ignition/update-config ........................ ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController  
  GET|HEAD        api/v1/note .......................................................................... note.index › NoteController@index  
  POST            api/v1/note .......................................................................... note.store › NoteController@store  
  GET|HEAD        api/v1/note/create ................................................................. note.create › NoteController@create  
  GET|HEAD        api/v1/note/{note} ..................................................................... note.show › NoteController@show  
  PUT|PATCH       api/v1/note/{note} ................................................................. note.update › NoteController@update  
  DELETE          api/v1/note/{note} ............................................................... note.destroy › NoteController@destroy  
  GET|HEAD        api/v1/note/{note}/edit ................................................................ note.edit › NoteController@edit  
  GET|HEAD        sanctum/csrf-cookie .................................. sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

**thunder request (same as postman)**
[Thunder Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfkhq.png)

**JSON Request**

```
{
  "title": "Hello World",
  "content": "Lorem ipsum."
}
```

Trying to make a JSON POST REQUEST and getting **Status: 405 Method Not Allowed** and I'm using php artisan serve, I could provide GIT project if necessary. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation rules look incorrect. In your `NoteRequest` class, the rules should be an associative array where the keys are the field names and the values are the validation rules. However, in your code, the rules are defined as a comma-separated list of strings. This might cause the validation to fail and return a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|max:255|min:3',
        'content' => 'nullable|max:255|min:10',
    ];
}
```